# How to display upsell products on the checkout page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, checkout, upselling

I want to display the upsell products on the checkout page. can anyone suggest the solution? I am using **Magento 1.9**.

Comment: You should check out http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step/.

Comment: I want to display upsell products on the checkout page, not to add a new step in the checkout process.

Comment: Then you should just call the block for upsell products on checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to know that : the **Up-sells** are nativelly displayed in `product view page`, it's the items that you would like your customer to buy instead of the product that he is viewing ! If you want to display them in checkout, It would not matter much because the customer has already chosen his product.

What you should display is rather the **Cross-sells**, they are usually displayed in the `shopping cart` page, this functionality is intended to make customers buy items they didn’t had in mind when they came to your site and you can set all this in your product via admin panel `product->manage products`

More information in [Inchoo article](http://inchoo.net/magento/related-products-up-sells-cross-sells-in-magento/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one block class and template that will be added on cart page. Load all the Cart Items products there like below:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
  $productObject = $item->getProduct()
}
```

Now as you got the `Product` Object check `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` block class `_prepareData` function. 
Use the same logic to fetch Upsell products are cart Items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productObject = $item->getProduct();
    $id = $productObject->getId();
    $upsell_product = $productObject->getUpSellProductCollection();  
}
```